# Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed Output: error: failed to open APK: Invalid file

Tags: java, android, gradle

**Device Info:**

windows 10
Android Studio 3.2 or 3.1

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip  
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

**Question:**
When I create a new Android Project,rebuilding cause this error.  I cannot find the solution in google or stackoverflow.  The error Log is
 "Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed  Output:  error: failed to open APK: Invalid file."
I don't know which APK a building need "open",and cannot find the key point.

I think maybe something wrong with my pc.
Can Anyone help?

**log:**

```
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
**Output:  error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.**

Command: C:\Users\RABBIT\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\1f6bc70d6f61581570fe3ce3ff0cfffc\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        D:\RA\PROGRAM\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        D:\RA\CODE\RA_CODE\Aapt2Test\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        D:\RA\CODE\RA_CODE\Aapt2Test\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @D:\RA\CODE\RA_CODE\Aapt2Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        D:\RA\CODE\RA_CODE\Aapt2Test\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.aapt.rabbit.aapttest\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        D:\RA\CODE\RA_CODE\Aapt2Test\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:177)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:823)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:525)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:275)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 2):

problem solved

It is because my company's PC has a **Encrypting Software**`http://www.wowostar.com`,it encrypt all files which were created when building.

**Need find the process name when building, and add to the Encrypting Software's whitelist.**

[image: find the process name]

Answer (score 0):

for my case i deleted the ids.xml file (it was useless in the project)

Answer (score 0):

For my case, add `aapt.exe`/`aapt2.exe` to the Encrypting Software whitelist